# Varioref, cleveref and autonum together

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref, autonum

I'm trying to mix varioref, cleveref and autonum to have the following behaviors:

- Automatic adding of reference type (i.e. adding "section" when referencing a section). -> cleveref;
- Adding the "on next/following page" -> varioref;
- Not numbering equations which are not referenced -> autonum.

Any combination of two of the three works well, but the three fail with undefined references.

A simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{varioref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{autonum}

\begin{document}

\begin{align} x \label{eqnx} \end{align} % referenced, must have number (1)
\begin{align} y \label{eqny} \end{align} % referenced, must have number (2)
\begin{align} z \label{eqnz} \end{align} % not referenced, must not have any number

\pagebreak

\vref{eqnx,eqny} %% Solution 1: What I'm looking for, does not work

% \cref{eqnx,eqny} \vpageref{eqnx,eqny} %% Solution 2: A different way of writing Solution 1. Works. Note that this is not really equal to Solution 1.

%\vref{eqnx,eqny} \ref{eqnx} \ref{eqny} %% Solution 3: WORKS, use vref as solution1, but there is also references using standard \ref

\end{document}
```

*Edit*: A solution was provided, but finally I think that not numbering equation, even if they are not referenced, is a bad practice because reviewers cannot easily reference them. So except for special use cases, I discourage the usage of `autonum`.

Comment: I tried `\usepackage{mathtools}\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true}` instead of `autonum` and `amsmath`, but no luck either. There are less errors if the math packages are loaded after the reference packages, though.

Comment: @Crissov, from what I have read, the mathtools package is deprecated in favor of autonum when used with cleveref because "autonum was designed to work with cleveref". Obviously it does not ;(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it seems you want the `\vref` command to work with **C**omma **S**eparated **L**ists, you should use `\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL{vref}` as in the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[%
  paperwidth=3in,
  paperheight=2in,
  margin=0.1in,
  bottom=0.3in,
  footskip=0pt]{geometry} % Only to get smaller pages for MWE

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{autonum}

\makeatletter
\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL{vref}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{align} x \label{eqnx} \end{align} % referenced, must have number (1)
\begin{align} y \label{eqny} \end{align} % referenced, must have number (2)
\begin{align} z \label{eqnz} \end{align} % not referenced, must not have any number

\pagebreak

\vref{eqnx,eqny}

\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1]

### [image: Page 2]

From section 3.3 "Reference commands" in the [documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/autonum/autonum.pdf):

> For reference commands expecting a comma separated list of label names as an
>   argument, you can use
>   `\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL{NewReferenceCommand}`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/autonum/autonum.pdf), one can use `\autonum@generatePatchedReference{NewReferenceCommand}` to make "normal reference commands expecting a single label name as an argument" work with autonum.

Adding the following should make things work:

```
\makeatletter
\autonum@generatePatchedReference{vref}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The correct thing here is to use `\autonum@generatePatchedReferenceCSL{vref}` since `vref` can be used with **C**omma **S**eparated **L**ists, as in OPs MWE.

Comment: Using the correction from @hooy this actually works. Thank you.